# Mouseover button and triggers svg circle same time

Tags: html, css, mouseover

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/cmwf5h7t/15/)

Im trying to trigger a mouseover change to fill the svg circle background color when hovering the button. Im unable to do that.

```css
.position-orange-circle { position: absolute; margin-top: 100px; }
.position-btn { background-color: #ffbb11; height: 41px; width: 130px; border: none; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 600; cursor: pointer; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; transition-duration: 0.4s;}
.position-btn:hover svg circle { background-color: #231f20 !important; color: #ffbb11 !important; border: #9c7002 solid 1px; fill: #ffbb11;}
```

```html
<svg height="150" width="150" class="position-orange-circle">
 <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" stroke="#ffbb11" stroke-width="5" fill="white"/>
</svg> 
      
<div class="btn-position">
 <button class="position-btn">Apply now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing's happening because you don't have a `chbg` JavaScript function, thus `chbg('red')` won't do anything more than throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: chbg is not defined`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge - I dont want to use JS unless I have to?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing the JS before I post on stackoverflow. That didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not navigate up the DOM using CSS. You can only access future siblings and children.

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

```css
.position-orange-circle { position: absolute; margin-top: 100px; left: 15px; }
.position-btn { background-color: #ffbb11; height: 41px; width: 130px; border: none; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 600; cursor: pointer; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; transition-duration: 0.4s;}
.position-btn:hover ~ .position-orange-circle > circle{ background-color: #231f20 !important; color: #ffbb11 !important; border: #9c7002 solid 1px; fill: #ffbb11;}
```

```html
<div class="btn-position">
<button class="position-btn">Apply now</button>
<svg height="150" width="150" class="position-orange-circle">
<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" stroke="#ffbb11" stroke-width="5" fill="white"/>
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - without JS! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS only solution. The structure is quite unconventional as the SVG is nested inside the BUTTON. It does what you describe but may or may not suit your use case:

```
<style>
svg {
  position: absolute;
  stroke: #ffbb11;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

button:hover svg {
  fill: #ffbb11;
}
</style>

<button>
  Hover
  <svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
  </svg>
</button>
```

See https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/zJWaEa

Answer (score 0):

As per @obsidian's Answer, it would be something like this:

```
function chbg(color) { 
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor.setAttribute("fill", "red")
}
```

if it's more `chbg(color, id, td, fc)`

```
function chbg(color, id, td, fc) { 
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration = td;
  document.getElementById(id).style.color = fc;
}
```

[Test](http://jsfiddle.net/NAuxn/4/)

Comment: I tried that before I posted an issue on SOF. It didnt fill the background inside the svg circle on jsfiddle - `fill:#ffbb11;`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you!

```js
function chbg(color) {
    document.getElementById("whiteCircle").setAttribute("fill", color);
}
```

```css
.position-orange-circle { position: absolute; margin-top: 100px; }
.position-btn { background-color: #ffbb11; height: 41px; width: 130px; border: none; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 600; cursor: pointer; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; transition-duration: 0.4s;}
.position-btn:hover svg circle { background-color: #231f20 !important; color: #ffbb11 !important; border: #9c7002 solid 1px; fill: #ffbb11;}
```

```html
<svg height="150" width="150" class="position-orange-circle">
 <circle id="whiteCircle" cx="60" cy="60" r="50" stroke="#ffbb11" stroke-width="5" fill="white"/>
</svg> 
      
<div class="btn-position">
 <button class="position-btn" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">Apply now</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mzb12pqs/